# why star rating is not saving?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

so i have wrote this code problem is when i click on stars it should be saved but it doesnt save when i check database i tried submit button too but didnt work it doesnt give any errors too :(

this is my model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
class Rating(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ratings')
    stars = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
```

and this is my view

```
def rate_comment(request, comment_id):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
    stars = request.POST.get('stars')
    if stars:
        Rating.objects.create(comment=comment, stars=stars)
    return redirect('blog/blog-detail.html', pk=comment.post.pk)
```

this is url.py

```
    path('<id>/', rate_comment, name='rate_comment'),
```

blog-detail.html:

```
    <div>
            <!-- start rating system -->
                    <div>
                                        
        {% for rating in comment.ratings.all %}
                {% for i in "12345" %}
                    {% if i|add:"-1" < rating.stars %}
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                {% else %}
                        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}

<div class="rating" style="text-align:center;" >
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="stars" value="5" />
  <label for="star5" class="fa fa-star"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="stars" value="4" />
  <label for="star4" class="fa fa-star"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="stars" value="3" />
  <label for="star3" class="fa fa-star"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="stars" value="2" />
  <label for="star2" class="fa fa-star"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="stars" value="1" />
  <label for="star1" class="fa fa-star"></label>
</div>
                <!-- end rating system -->
```

i cant find the problem now

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your view :

````
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
    if request.method=="POST":
        stars = request.POST['stars']
        rate=Rating.objects.create(comment=comment, stars=stars)
        rate.save()
    return redirect('blog/blog-detail.html', pk=comment.post.pk)```
````

Comment: well it didn't make any changes

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<div class="rating" style="text-align:center;">
    <form action="{% url 'rate_comment' comment_id=comment.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="stars" value="5" />
        <label for="star5" class="fa fa-star"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="stars" value="4" />
        <label for="star4" class="fa fa-star"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="stars" value="3" />
        <label for="star3" class="fa fa-star"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="stars" value="2" />
        <label for="star2" class="fa fa-star"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="stars" value="1" />
        <label for="star1" class="fa fa-star"></label>
        <button type="submit">Rate</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

change urls

```
path('<int:comment_id>/', rate_comment, name='rate_comment')
```

Comment: problem is :    <form action="{% url 'rate_comment' comment_id=comment.id %}" method="post">

 Reverse for 'rate_comment' not found. 'rate_comment' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: path('rate_comment/<int:comment_id>/', rate_comment, name='rate_comment') rearrange the path.. and redirect blog-detail.